# On checkbox checked, make another checkbox required

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I haven't been successful with getting this to work properly, but I have gotten the show/hide portion to work on my form.

**Here is what I'm trying to achieve**:
- When the `My transaction data` or `Information about my device...` is checked, make the last checkbox required.
- When BOTH top checkboxes are checked, make the last checkbox required.

[image]

**Here is my attempt, but it doesn't work**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rtd3Transaction').change(function() {
        if ($('#rtdConfirm').attr('required')) {
            $('#rtdConfirm').removeAttr('required');
        }
        else {
            $('#rtdConfirm').attr('required','required');
        }
    });

    $('#rtd3Device').change(function() {
        if ($('#rtdConfirm').attr('required')) {
            $('#rtdConfirm').removeAttr('required');
        }
        else {
            $('#rtdConfirm').attr('required','required');
        }
    });

    $('#rtd3Transaction, #rtd3Device').change(function() {
        if ($('#rtd3Transaction').checked && $('#rtd3Transaction').checked) {
            $('#rtdConfirm').attr('required','required');
        }
        else {
            $('#rtdConfirm').removeAttr('required');
        }
    }); });
```

**Code**:

```html
        <div id='form-wrapper-certain'>
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-11">
                    <i>You must specify the personal information you would like us to delete:</i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-11">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3Transaction" name="rtd[3][checked][]" value="transaction">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3Transaction">My transaction data</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-11">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3Device" name="rtd[3][checked][]" value="device">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3Device">Information about my device(s) collected through cookies and other automated collection tools</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='form-wrapper-certain-selection'>
                <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3Confirm" name="rtd[3][confirm]" value="yes">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3Confirm">I confirm that I would like not to sell your personal information to third parties.</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: So basically, you're asking for something that requires the last checkbox if either or both of the first two are checked? Just to make sure I understand.

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554358/make-input-section-required-when-both-checkboxes-are-selected) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click event of #rtd3Transaction, #rtd3Device check is if one or both check box is checked than add required. if required is already added than avoid to add it.and if both check box is not checked than remove checked from third one.
check required already added using **!$('#rtd3Confirm').prop('required')**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
    $('#rtd3Transaction, #rtd3Device').click(function() {
        if ($('#rtd3Transaction').prop('checked')==true || $('#rtd3Device').prop('checked')==true) {
        if(!$('#rtd3Confirm').prop('required')){
            $('#rtd3Confirm').attr('required','required');
         }
        }else if($('#rtd3Transaction').prop('checked') != true && $('#rtd3Transaction').prop('checked')!=true) {
            $('#rtd3Confirm').removeAttr('required');
        }
    }); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='form-wrapper-certain'>
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-11">
                    <i>You must specify the personal information you would like us to delete:</i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-11">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3Transaction" name="rtd[3][checked][]" value="transaction">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3Transaction">My transaction data</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-11">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3Device" name="rtd[3][checked][]" value="device">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3Device">Information about my device(s) collected through cookies and other automated collection tools</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='form-wrapper-certain-selection'>
                <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtd3Confirm" name="rtd[3][confirm]" value="yes">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtd3Confirm">I confirm that I would like not to sell your personal information to third parties.</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are over thinking (and over coding). You do not need to check if both checkboxes are checked if checking either one is enough. So remove the first two change() methods and modify the last one to check the statuses of 2 checkboxes and decide the requirement.

```
   $('#rtd3Transaction, #rtd3Device').on('change', function() {
        if ($('#rtd3Transaction').prop('checked') == true || 
            $('#rtd3Device').prop('checked') == true)
        {
            $('#rtdConfirm').attr('required','required');
        }
        else {
            $('#rtdConfirm').removeAttr('required');
        }
    });
```

Note we use `.prop('checked')` to see if a checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `||` operator instead of `&&`? This would require the last checkbox if either of the first two (or both) are checked:

```
$('#rtd3Transaction, #rtd3Device').change(function() {
    if ($('#rtd3Transaction').checked || $('#rtdDevice').checked) {
        $('#rtdConfirm').attr('required','required');
    } else {
        $('#rtdConfirm').removeAttr('required');
    }
}
```

And frankly, jQuery might be a bit overkill here (unless you are already using it for other things), so here's a plain modern JS solution:

```
let rtd3Transaction = document.getElementById("rtd3Transaction");
let rtd3Device = document.getElementById("rtd3Device");
[rtd3Transaction, rtdDevice].forEach(element=>{
    element.addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
        let rtdConfirm = document.getElementById("rtdConfirm");
        if (rtd3Transaction.checked || rtdDevice.checked) {
            rtdConfirm.required = "required";
        } else {
            rtdConfirm.removeAttribute('required');
        }
    });
});
```